# andriod sdkmanager doesn't work . win 11(X64) .Error: A JNI error has occurred

Tags: android, flutter

## Target: install android SDK correclty to develop flutter app.

---

environment：
operate system: win 11(22H2)
java-version:1.8
cmdline-tools version : commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest
steps:
Yes 1. download andriod sdkmanager from offical web site.
Yes 2. unzip 'cmdline-tools' and copy to D:\android
No  3. execute sdkmanager.bat which in 'D:\android\cmdline-tools\bin>'

error:

```
    D:\android\cmdline-tools\bin> .\sdkmanager.bat
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:       
    com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the
    Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class
    file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
```

redo the steps，but the result is same.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error while Setting Flutter and Android Studio Setup.
It was due to two different java versions on my machine as I required older version i.e JAVA 8 for JavaFX. I solved it by changing path of **JAVA_HOME** of System Variables from Environment With path of **jbr** File of Androd in C Drive. ie. C>Program Files>Android>Android Studio>jbr. And the error was solved for Flutter Installation.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this question by upgrage jdk to "17.0.7"